# Esconder e mostrar um icon em mat-table angular 7

Tags: angular-7

Galera, tenho uma mat-table do material angular, estou usando angular 7, tenho dois botões, um de play e outro de pause, começa mostrando os botões de play nesta lista, estou tentando implementar uma lógica para, quando o usuário clicar no play na linha correspondente, apenas ele suma para poder mostrar o botão de pause, mas apenas na linha clicada, (ícone tem função de botão)segue cógido

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="action">
 <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action </th>
 <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let poster; let i = index"> 
     <mat-icon [id]="row-click" matTooltip="Metas de campanhas" (click)="getAction()">play_circle_outline</mat-icon> 
     <mat-icon [id]="row-click" matTooltip="Metas de campanhas" (click)="getAction()">pause_circle_outline</mat-icon>
</td>
```

Monstra primeiro a lista de plays e se clicar no play então mostra apenas o pause daquela linha em questão, alguém ?

Comment: Você pode utilizar jquery?

Comment: Não André, senão vai ficar "gambi" rsrsrs

Comment: É interessante usar os recursos do próprio Angular

Comment: Utilize o *ngIf ele pode validar isso

Comment: @OtavioCapel eu já fiz ngif, porém ainda não consegui acertar a lógica para tal ...

Comment: Você pode criar uma variavel: `play: boolean = false`isso fara com que o botão de play seja mostrado primeiro. ai nos icones vc faz :
 <mat-icon *ngIf="!play"> PLAY  </mat-icon> 
 <mat-icon *ngIf="play"> PAUSE  </mat-icon> 
Ao usuario aperta play você inverte o valor da variavel.

Comment: Então, eu fiz desta forma, porém, pelo fato de ser uma lista, no caso uma tabela, já fiz isso mas ele some todos os plays e vice-versa, entendeu ... ?

Comment: a lógica é clicar o primeiro icon de play da tabela e apenas ele mudar

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução (não tão elegante) é adicionar uma propriedade a mais ao teu dataSource como sendo um boolean, "pausado" por ex.

Os métodos de play e pause seriam os responsáveis por setar essa variável da respectiva linha do dataSource, já dentro do `<td></td>` tu só verifica essa variável com o *ngIf